# Finding the orthogonal trajectory of $y = x + ce^{-x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I encountered this question on a finals study guide but my attempts to solve it were unsuccessful.

$y = x + ce^{-x}$

$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = 1 - ce^{-x}$

$\frac{-\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} y} = 1 - ce^{-x}$

I do not know where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a family of curves $$y = x + ce^{-x}, \, c \text{ arbitrary}\tag 1$$ parametrized by $c.$  then $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 -ce^{-x} \tag 2$$ eliminating $c$ between $(1)$ and (2), we find that $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 + x - y $$ and a family of curve that is orthogonal to the curves deined by $(1)$ is given by $$-\frac{dx}{dy} = 1 + x - y.$$

a particular solution is $x = y-2 $ so the general solution is $$x = y-2 + de^{-y} \tag 3$$  therefore $(3)$ and $(1)$ are two families of orthogonal curves parametrized by $c$  and $d.$

Comment: @AmirOmidi, you are welcome.