# Find the orthogonal trajectories of the family, $y=x+C e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My try: We solve for $C$ and apply explicit differentiation
$$
y=x+C e^{-x} \Rightarrow C=\frac{y-x}{e^{-x}}
$$
$$
\frac{d y}{d x}=1+x-y
$$
For the orthogonal trajectories, we replace $\frac{d y}{d x}$ by $-\frac{d x}{d y}$
$$
-\frac{d x}{d y}=x-y+1
$$

I found the same question but it is still not clear to me how the particular solution was found.
[Finding the orthogonal trajectory of $y = x + ce^{-x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319174/finding-the-orthogonal-trajectory-of-y-=-x-+-ce%5E%7B-x%7D)

Comment: As a matter of form you should include the problem statement in the body of of the Question, not only in the title.  A concern about "how the particular solution was found" could have a special sense for linear ODEs, so it would help clarify your meaning if you went into more detail about what difficulty you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$-\frac{d x}{d y}=x-y+1$$
$$x'+x=y-1$$
Use the integrating factor $ \mu = e^y$:
$$(xe^y)'=e^y(y-1)$$
Integrate.

---

For the other method.
Solve the homogeneous DE:
$$x'=-x$$
$$x_g=ce^{-y}$$
Then try the particular solution
$$x_p=ay+b$$
Then the solution of the DE is
$$x=x_g+x_p$$